# SQLalchemy Bulk insert with one to one relation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following model where TableA and TableB have 1 to 1 relationship:

```
class TableA(db.Model):
    id = Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(1024))
    table_b = relationship('TableB', uselist=False, back_populates="table_a")


class TableB(db.Model):
    id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(TableA.id), primary_key=True)
    a = relationship('TableA', back_populates='table_b')
    name = Column(String(1024))
```

when I insert 1 record everything goes fine:

```
rec_a = TableA(title='hello')
rec_b = TableB(a=rec_a, name='world')
db.session.add(rec_b)
db.session.commit()
```

but when I try to do this for bulk of records:

```
bulk_ = []

for title, name in zip(titles, names):
    rec_a = TableA(title=title)
    bulk_.append(TableB(a=rec_a, name=name))

db.session.bulk_save_objects(bulk_)
db.session.commit()
```

I get the following exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")
```

Am I doing something wrong? Did I configure the model wrong?
Is there a way to bulk commit this type of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you see is thrown by Mysql. It is complaining that the attempt to insert records into `table_b` violates the foreign key constraint.

One technique could be to write all the titles in one bulk statement, then write all the names in a 2nd bulk statement. Also, I've never passed relationships successfully to bulk operations, to this method relies on inserting simple values.

```
bulk_titles = [TableA(title=title) for title in titles]
session.bulk_save_objects(bulk_titles, return_defauls=True)
bulk_names = [TableB(id=title.id, name=name) for title, name in zip(bulk_titles, names)]
session.bulk_save_objects(bulk_names)
```

`return_defaults=True` is needed above because we need `title.id` in the 2nd bulk operation. But this [greatly reduces the performance gains of the bulk operation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects.params.return_defaults)

To avoid the performance degradation due to `return_defauts=True`, you could generate the primary keys from the application, rather than the database, e.g. using uuids, or fetching the max id in each table and generating a range from that start value.

Another technique *might* be to write your bulk insert statement using sqlalchemy core or plain text.