# How to resolve related foreign key at insert time using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

#### Motivations

I have data coming from a source that I interface with pandas DataFrame.
I have a datamodel interfaced by SQLAlchemy ORM.
I have normalized the datamodel into two tables for MCVE sake:

- `channel` holding metadata about records (small volumetry, ~1k rows);
- `record` holding record pointing to `channel` (higher volumetry, 90k rows/day).

The aim of `channel` is to avoid repetition. What I want is to setup a pythonic insertion of data into `record` table using SQLAlchemy with the constraint the data source does not know about `channelid`.

#### Data Source

Here a sample of data from the source (the only data I have access):

```
import pandas as pd
recs = [
    {'serial': '1618741320', 'source': 1, 'channel': 4, 'timestamp': pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 08:35:00'), 'value': 12},
    {'serial': '1350397285', 'source': 2, 'channel': 3, 'timestamp': pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 09:20:00'), 'value': 37},
    {'serial': '814387724', 'source': 2, 'channel': 1, 'timestamp': pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 12:30:00'), 'value': 581},
    {'serial': '545914014', 'source': 3, 'channel': 0, 'timestamp': pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 01:45:00'), 'value': 0},
    {'serial': '814387724', 'source': 0, 'channel': 5, 'timestamp': pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 14:20:00'), 'value': 699}
]
data = pd.DataFrame(recs)
```

Here a sample of meta stored in `channel` that have been learned from the setup.

```
recs = [
    {'channelid': 28, 'serial': '545914014', 'source': 3, 'channel': 0},
    {'channelid': 73, 'serial': '1350397285', 'source': 2, 'channel': 3},
    {'channelid': 239, 'serial': '1618741320', 'source': 1, 'channel': 4},
    {'channelid': 245, 'serial': '814387724', 'source': 0, 'channel': 5},
    {'channelid': 259, 'serial': '814387724', 'source': 2, 'channel': 1}
]
meta= pd.DataFrame(recs)
```

#### MCVE

First let's start with a MCVE!

We define the datamodel:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()
Engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres")

class Channel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'channel'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('serial', 'source', 'channel'),)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial = Column(String, nullable=False)
    source = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    channel = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'record'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('channelid', 'timestamp'),)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    channelid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('channel.id'), nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    channel = relationship("Channel")

Base.metadata.drop_all(Engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(Engine)
```

And we feed the `channel` table to reflect meta we already have:

```
with Engine.connect() as dbcon:
    dbcon.execute(Channel.__table__.insert(), meta.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

#### Issue to solve

Now we would like to easily insert `data` into `record` table, but unfortunately we lack the `channelid` from our datasource (which does not know about it). Obviously this call fails:

```
with Engine.connect() as dbcon:
    with dbcon.begin() as dbtrans:
        dbcon.execute(Record.__table__.insert(), data.to_dict(orient='records'))
        dbtrans.commit()
```

Because of:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "channelid" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (6, null, 2019-01-01 08:35:00, 12).
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO record (timestamp, value) VALUES (%(timestamp)s, %(value)s)'] [parameters: ({'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 08:35:00'), 'value': 12}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 09:20:00'), 'value': 37}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 12:30:00'), 'value': 581}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 01:45:00'), 'value': 0}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 14:20:00'), 'value': 699})]
```

We could handle it with pandas:

```
meta = pd.read_sql("SELECT id AS channelid, serial, source, channel FROM channel;", Engine.connect())
full = data.merge(meta, on=['serial', 'source', 'channel'])
```

And the previous call will work because the association with `channelid` is done:

```
   channel      serial  source           timestamp  value  channelid
0        4  1618741320       1 2019-01-01 08:35:00     12        239
1        3  1350397285       2 2019-01-01 09:20:00     37         73
2        1   814387724       2 2019-01-01 12:30:00    581        259
3        0   545914014       3 2019-01-01 01:45:00      0         28
4        5   814387724       0 2019-01-01 14:20:00    699        245
```

But this not the way I think it should be solved, mainly because it makes me perform the binding with pandas instead of SQLAlchemy.

I also have tried this, but it is totally inefficient for a dataset of 90k records:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=Engine)
session = Session()
with session.begin_nested() as trans:
    for rec in data.to_dict(orient='records'):
        c = session.query(Channel).filter_by(**{k: rec.pop(k) for k in ['serial', 'source', 'channel']}).first()
        r = Record(channelid=c.id, **rec)
        session.add(r)
```

It takes almost 100 times longer than previous method using DataFrame.

#### Question

I have focused my energy in building a comprehensive MCVE because I am more fluent in pandas than SQLAlchemy and I could not find a solution to my problem in the SQLAlchemy documentation.

My question is: *"How can I resolve the `channelid` to make my insert successful, in a fashion that is performant and relies on SQLAclhemy instead of pandas?"*

Feel free to comment to improve this post. What am I looking for is a rational way to do it. It can imply to update the datamodel, I have this flexibility.

#### Update

Reading more about SQLAlchemy and testing proposals `@Ramasubramanian S`, the best I could achieve is:

```
ukeys = ['serial', 'source', 'channel']
with session.begin_nested() as trans:
    g = data.groupby(ukeys)
    for key in g.groups:
        recs = []
        for rec in data.loc[g.groups[key],:].to_dict(orient='records'):
            m = {k: rec.pop(k) for k in ukeys}
            c = session.query(Channel).filter_by(**m).first()
            #r = Record(channel=c, **rec)  
            r = Record(channelid=c.id, **rec) # Bulk Insert needs explicit id not a relationship
            recs.append(r)
        #session.add_all(recs)
        session.bulk_save_objects(recs) # Not working w/ relationship
```

Using relationship `Record(channel=c, **rec)` the method `session.bulk_save_objects` raises:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « channelid »
DETAIL:  La ligne en échec contient (1, null, 2019-01-01 08:35:00, 12)

[SQL: INSERT INTO record (timestamp, value) VALUES (%(timestamp)s, %(value)s)]
[parameters: ({'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 08:35:00'), 'value': 12}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 09:20:00'), 'value': 37}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 12:30:00'), 'value': 581}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 01:45:00'), 'value': 0}, {'timestamp': Timestamp('2019-01-01 14:20:00'), 'value': 699})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Then `channelid` is set to `NULL`, it seems it cannot use `relationship` capability, thus we need to explicitly pass `channelid` to make it works.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with SQL Alchmey but having had a brief look over the documentation it is SQL, right? Can you not create the two tables seperately and then join them? Something like this:

```query(Record).join(Channel)


       filter(Record.serial==Channel.serial)
       filter(Record.source==Channel.source)
      filter (Record.channel==Channel.channel   )```

Comment: @FiercestJim, it is an insert query, records do not exist at this point.

Comment: Yes I understand that. If SQL Alchemy uses normal SQL logic I don't see how you could create a table from two different sources without creating them each separately first and then joining those two tables together on the specified keys. The result of this join being the table you want.
In your pandas example I think you are doing exactly this.

Comment: @FiercestJim, that is I am wondering if there is a way the ORM can resolve foreign key at insert time without having the need to use extraneous data-structure or temporary table.

Answer (score 5):

One way to improve the performance of inserting multiple records is to create the objects and insert into the database in bulk using either [bulk_save_objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects) or [bulk_insert_mappings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings).

[This link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow) shows the performance comparison of various methods of inserting multiple records.

You can find a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386359/sqlalchemy-bulk-insert-with-one-to-one-relation)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for answering, can you detail a bit how your solution address the foreign key resolution?

Comment: As per the example in yoyr post, you would have to create all the Channel objects and insert them in bulk using bulk_save_objects. Then create the list of Record objects and repeat the same. There is a link to a question with a similar use case in my answer. There is a good code sample for the same.

Comment: I have seen it (I basically did the same in my MCVE). Does it means there is no automatic foreign key resolution and it is my duty to implement the logic that resolves it.

Comment: If by "Automatic foreign key resolution" you mean to insert into tables with a single statement,  I am not sure if it is possible. But the difference between you MCVE and my suggestion is you would insert the list of objects for table 1 in one single go, and you create the list of objects for table 2 and do the same. Using one of the "bulk_" methods you would have significant improvement in performance, which was what I thought the question was.

Comment: I have tested your proposal and updated my post accordingly. The main fact is `bulk_save_objects` cannot use `relationship` capability. It is a bit fuzzy to me to understand which is the best option to choose.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key to the solution is in your statement

> channel holding metadata about records (small volumetry, ~1k rows);

Since you are saying this is not too high, i would just cache this in the memory

```py
channels = session.query(Channel).all()

channel_map = {}
for c in channels:
    channel_map['-'.join([c.serial, c.source, c.channel])] = c.id
```

And now you can do the bulk update or any other way you prefer

```py
with session.begin_nested() as trans:
    recs = []
    for rec in data.to_dict(orient='records'):
        channel_id = channel_map['-'.join([rec['serial'], rec['source'], rec['channel']])]
        r = Record(channelid=channel_id, **rec) # Bulk Insert needs explicit id not a relationship
        recs.append(r)
    session.add_all(recs)
```

Note: Above is untested code but intention is to show a possible approach

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am not sure about uniqueness of `'-'.join([c.serial, c.source, c.channel])` because `serial` is a string with no restriction. We could use a tuple `(c.serial, c.source, c.channel)` instead which hashes properly (all elements are immutable). Instead of a cache, I have chosen to group by the dataframe in order to create required `Channel` object only once.